# URL not loading in Firefox(Selenium)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide, geckodriver

i have created a jar with a relative path(means i have given the geckodriver inside the resources and mapped it) but the problem is firefox launches but url is not getting loaded. i need it to run on multiple systems running multiple operating systems. Can anyone help?

```
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentTest;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.LogStatus;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;


public class Maintest {

    public static FirefoxDriver driver;
    //public static ChromeDriver driver;
    public static String downloadPath = "/home/user/Desktop/Downloads";
    private static ExtentReports reports;


    @BeforeTest

    public static void createDriver() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", "/home/user/Desktop/geckodriver");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(FirefoxDriverProfile());
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    public static FirefoxProfile FirefoxDriverProfile() {
        FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", downloadPath);
        profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/octet-stream");
        profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/csv, application/pdf,application/octet-stream");
        profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/pdf,application/x-pdf, application/pdf,application/vnd.fdf,application/vnd.ppdf, application/acrobat, applications/vnd.pdf, text/pdf, text/x-pdf, application/vnd.cups-pdf, application/foxit");
        profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile",
                "text/csv,application/x-msexcel,application/excel,application/x-excel,application/vnd.ms-excel,image/png,image/jpeg,text/html,text/plain,application/msword,application/xml/application/pdf");
        profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",
                "text/csv,application/x-msexcel,application/excel,application/x-excel,application/vnd.ms-excel,image/png,image/jpeg,text/html,text/plain,application/msword,application/xml/application/pdf");
        profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
        profile.setPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);
        profile.setPreference("plugin.scan.Acrobat", "99.0");
        profile.setPreference("plugin.scan.plid.all", false);
        profile.setPreference("plugin.disable_full_page_plugin_for_types", "application/pdf");
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", false);
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting", false);
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", false);
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", false);
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", false);
        return profile;
    }

    @Test

    public static void bridge(List<String> selectedList) throws Exception {
        createDriver();
        System.out.println("###############"+new Date()+"###############\n\n");
        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        Date date = new Date();
        String dateTime = format.format(date);
        reports = new ExtentReports("/home/user/Desktop/Regression Results-"+dateTime+".html", true);
       driver.get("http://sitename");
```

Comment: Is it working with other browsers?

Comment: nope. url doesn't load in any browser

Comment: please take a look at the code above. it works on the machine i developed the script on but not on other machine with firefox 49 and above. using a jar file to run it.

Answer (score 0):

Known issue it occurs when you are using geckodriver lower version ,One more to add check the gecko driver version is compatible or not with your given environment.
You can download the latest version from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

Comment: Can you provide more details about your enviornment

Comment: intellij 16.3, gecko v0.14.0. able to run it till FF 48 Version. its an entire site automated using selenium and java. FF 49,50 and 51 not working. i need it to run it on different machines running different os and firefox versions.

Comment: Use the latest selenium 3.1.0 ,latest gecko v0.14.0 in FF 49,50,

Comment: To run the scripts you have to use latest selenium ,gecko versions 
for download latest selenium http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/
and gecko https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
Checked with FF version 50,51,52.

Comment: i have it working through intellij on all  versions, but when i make a jar and copy it to other machines. it wont work.